# Why android:tint="" produce a bad resolution Image?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I'm using vector's in my **app** with the common way: `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_camera"`.

When I use the vector without `android:tint=""` attribute the image appear in a good condition and resolution:

[image]

But when I add the `android:tint=""` attribute the image appear in bad condition and resolution:

[image]

What I missing here?

Comment: What if you use only src=""

Comment: @Khemraj The same!

Comment: This is a vector icon or png

Comment: @Khemraj I reminded that in my question at first line, however I'm using verctor